# How to echo span with if else

Tags: php

Encountered this error when trying to do if else to echo with this.

i have tried using htmlentities but it is still the same

```php
if ($row["Status"] == 'ONLINE') {#
  echo htmlentities('<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>');
  echo '<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>'
} else {#
  echo htmlentities('<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>');
  echo '<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>'
}
```

Comment: Why is there a # after the curly brace?  Btw, what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid confusion about single quotes and double quotes etc is to remember that php is a template language.

If you are printing something, that should mean that all your logic has already been accomplished and now you’re just outputting the view: I.e., you’re writing HTML with PHP injected for looping or conditional output.

For example,

```
// end of php logic
?>
<!— html output follows —>
<?php if($row[‘Status’] == ‘ONLINE’): ?>
<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>
<?php else: ?>
<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>
<?php ending; ?>
```

Or, better yet, don’t repeat yourself:

```
<?php 
$status = $row[‘Status’] == ‘ONLINE’ ? ‘Online’ : ‘Offline’; 
$css = $row[‘Status’] == ‘ONLINE’ ? ‘success’ : ‘danger’;
?>
<span class="label label-<?= $css ?> label-rounded"><?= $status?></span>
```

Comment: I repeated myself a bit with setting the variables; that could be done better but I’m typing on a phone...

Answer (score 1):

If we wish to `echo` online and offline status, we can define two strings for instance for our HTMLs, then we would be having an `if` statement, maybe similar to:

```
$online_html = '<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span><span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>';

$offline_html = '<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span><span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>';

if ($row["Status"] == 'ONLINE') {
    echo $online_html;
} else {
    echo $offline_html;
}
```

Or:

```
if ($row["Status"] == 'ONLINE') {
    echo '<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span><span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span><span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>';
}
```

Or skip the if else completely:

```
$html['ONLINE'] = '<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span><span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>';    
$html['OFFLINE'] = '<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span><span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>';

echo $html[$row["Status"]];
```

Comment: It wasn't enough to be a own answer so I just added it as another example in yours.

Comment: I wouldn't say any of them is better than the other. It mostly depends on how many times this needs to be echoed. If it's only once then a simple if/else like your second code block shows is probably the best since it doesn't save anything in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can put html entries outside `php` codes.

```
<?php
if($row["Status"] == 'ONLINE') {
?>
<span class="label label-success label-rounded">Online</span>
<?php   
} 
else{
?>
<span class="label label-danger label-rounded">Offline</span>
<?php
}
?>
```